# How do I perform relational division using DQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

When trying to perform relational division using Doctrine 1.2, I receive a "Duplicate alias" error over what seems like the DISTINCT found in the query below:

```
SELECT 
    Data.ID  
FROM 
    Data 
INNER JOIN 
    TaggedData ON (Data.id = TaggedData.data_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag ON (Tag.id = TaggedData.tag_id) 
WHERE 
    Tag.id IN ('1' , '2') 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag.iD)=2
```

If I remove *DISTINCT* from the query, it runs but doesn't get me what I want.  Is there a proper way to get Doctrine past this issue?

### Specific code:

```
    $query = $this->createQuery("p")
        ->select("p.*")
        ->innerJoin("p.Data s")
        ->innerJoin("s.Tags c")
    ;
    $query
        ->andWhereIn("c.id", $tags)
        ->addHaving("COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = ?", count($tags))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning only a single value, just execute the raw SQL:

```
    $sql = <<<SQL

SELECT 
    Data.ID  
FROM 
    Data 
INNER JOIN 
    TaggedData ON (Data.id = TaggedData.data_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag ON (Tag.id = TaggedData.tag_id) 
WHERE 
    Tag.id IN ('1' , '2') 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag.iD)=2

SQL;

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('connection_name');
    $id = $conn->fetchOne($sql);
```

Comment: My example simplified a bit too much in this case.  I will be returning several instances of objects as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause to use having without distinct.
So i guess that if you add `GROUP BY Data.ID` just before `HAVING` all should be fine.

Comment: Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12711729/128991 - this seems to work in regular SQL, I'm just trying to bend it into DQL now.

Comment: Perhaps it's not necessary to add a group by, but using `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is not a best practice. By the way, i'm not a Doctrine expert but `->groupBy('Data.ID')` should solve your problem

Comment: Nah, the problem here is definitely Doctrine related.  It keeps bugging out on the DISTINCT being in the HAVING.

Comment: As it turns out, I did need it after switching to doing the query raw!  Thanks for at least mentioning this as I do believe it's solved my last issue.